# Your battery has been infected with 2 viruses. Click to remove. Phone vibrates like crazy :'(

Tags: samsung

My colleague was surfing the net with my NEW android in my absence. I do not know what he surfed but when I clicked "back" in the browser ..It took me to a website called "cookmobiapps.xyz" and my mobile just started vibrating continuously with a message "your battery is infected with 2 viruses, hit OK to remove. DO NOT LEAVE WEBPAGE" Everything on the screen froze so I clicked OK, then a screen appeared asking me to download an app from googleplay (which I didnt). My phone works fine now and I have not tried hitting the back button again. Why did this happen? What was that message about? Its a new phone and Im very worried :'(

Comment: No problems are there with your phone. It was the browser which caused that vibration and it did so because that popup/website told it to do so. Coupled with that scary message is what constitutes a typical phishing attempt on Android devices. *Always ignore  whatever they say or recommend, no matter what*. Since they are inconvenient, switch to an ad blocker. Let us know when the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hmm.  Can any components of the power source house any executable code?

Answer (score 1):

Reposted from comments by user154667:

> I installed 360 Security antivirus for Android, which detected a malware (that I removed). I deleted the history, cookies, cache, etc. I cleared the cache through some app manager, and it worked. I'm not getting those malicious websites now when I hit Back.